# Typecasting two Lists Giving Exception in C#

Tags: c#

I have two lists

```
List<RServer.V_CafLogistic>  lst1 ;
List<V_CafLogistic>  lst2;
```

where `V_CafLogistic` class structure is identical in both the namespace.

Please suggest me the way to typecast lst1 to lst2

(I tried `convertAll()`, `cast()` but they are thwoing expception invalid cast.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RServer.V_CafLogistic, V_CafLogistic>();
                var destinationList = Mapper.Map<List<RServer.V_CafLogistic>, List<V_CafLogistic>>(lst1);
```

Comment: thanx your answer is what i was looking after i got to know about AutoMapper.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that. They are two different classes. The fact that they're structurally identical means nothing to the runtime. You'll have to manually convert each object (or use a library like AutoMapper to do that automatically)

Example using AutoMapper:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<RServer.V_CafLogistic, V_CafLogistic>();
List<V_CafLogistic> lst2 = Mapper.Map<List<V_CafLogistic>, List<RServer.V_CafLogistic>>(lst1);
```

More info can be found here: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Getting-started

Comment: Glad to help! (Remember to mark the answer as correct for future visitors of this question)

Comment: Can you show me how to convert these two lists using AutoMapper.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this:

```
List<RServer.V_CafLogistic>  lst1;
List<V_CafLogistic> lst2=lst1
                   .Select (l =>new  V_CafLogistic()
                    {
                       /*copy properties here*/
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: i have 150 such lists Arion,so your way is not acceptable for me.though its correct.thanx anyways!!

Answer (score -1):

use the Enumerable.Cast<> `like lst1.Cast<V_CafLogistic>()`

Comment: You can't do that, they're two different classes

Comment: How is this answer different from Ehsans answer?